# how to find which integer no is maximim out of given numbers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x, y, z, result, max;
    printf("\nInput the first integer: "); 
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("\nInput the second integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("\nInput the third integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);
    result=(x+y+abs(x-y))/2;
    max=(result+z+abs(result-z))/2;
    printf("\nMaximum value of three integers: %d", max);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

unable to understand the formula:

```
result=(x+y+abs(x-y))/2;
max=(result+z+abs(result-z))/2;
```

Comment: I don't see it either, although a good reason not to use it is because there can be integer overflow. And because it's unclear code.

Comment: then how to solveit

Comment: With comparisons, or a compound ternary expression (which is comparisons anyway).

Comment: This honestly looks like the person you asked to let you copy their homework tried explicitly to get you into trouble by springing the trap of not being able to explain it to the teacher. You wisely sought help with understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this expression:

```
(x+y+abs(x-y))/2
```

If x => y, then `abs(x-y)` is the same as `x-y`.  That gives us: (x+y+(x-y))/2 == (x+x+y-y)/2 ==  2x/2 == x.

If x < y, then `abs(x-y)` is the same as `y-x`.  That gives us: (x+y+(y-x))/2 == (x-x+y+y)/2 ==  2y/2 == y.

So the above expression evaluates to the larger of `x` and `y` without using any conditionals.  The following expression `(result+z+abs(result-z))/2` does the same thing with `z` and the max of `x` and `y`.

Note however that this method has the potential to cause overflow.  The cleanest way to do this is to explicitly compare:

```
if (x >= y && x >= z) {
    max = x;
} else if (y >= x && y >= z) {
    max = y;
} else  {
    max = z;
}
```

Comment: `y >= x` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

> then how to solveit – Ujjwal Bhardwaj 5 mins ago

```
int max(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a > b ? (a > c ? a : c) : (b > c ? b : c);
}
```

Comment: This does not explain the formula. It gives another way of getting the result.

Comment: @JimRhodes I have answered another question, you have another. Is it the reason to DV

Comment: But it answers the question title *"how to find which integer no is maximim out of given numbers"*. The computation method can break.

Comment: @JimRhodes This answers the only question in this page, the one in the title, though it lacks a "?". The question how the formula can be explained is NOT asked here. Though OP does mention they do not understand the formula, this is much less of a question than the title. One question at a time. This answers the first and most obviously asked question. The question "Which vulnerabilities does my shown code expose?" is not answered either, though it is as clearly asked as the one about the formula.

Answer (score 1):

One way to visualize it is:

Imagine you have 2 trees. One is 16 meter tall and the other is 20 meter tall.

You look at their average, which is the “midpoint” and is 18 meter tall.  Now, what’s their difference? 4 meter.

You take 18 and add half of that difference, is 20 (the max). Likewise, you can take the average and minus half of the difference and it is the min.

So,

```
  average plus half the difference
= (x + y) / 2 + abs(x - y) / 2
= (x + y + abs(x - y)) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code returns the value of whichever is greater, `x` or `y`.

```
result = (x + y + abs(x - y)) / 2;
```

By adding the absolute value of the difference between `x` and `y`to the sum of `x` and `y` you essentially get 2 times the larger number. For example, if x=5 and y=20 then abs(x - y) = 15. So 5 + 20 + 15 = 40 which is 2 times the larger number. Divide that by 2 and you have determined larger value. Then by repeating the formula with the result above and `z` you have calculated the largest of the three.